# 3rd Party load CSV into Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, csv

I'm looking into a solution to allow a 3rd party to load a CSV into Marketing cloud.

The solution we're converging on is building a page, with a browse-save file dialog. The 3rd part can manually submit or script a post call to the url.

Where I'm unclear is how best to receive the CSV into Marketing Cloud.

We can save it into Portfolio, but getting it out and parsing is not self-evidently possible.

(Why FTP is not an option - it seems that it's difficult to control access at a folder level with the FTP accounts.)

Comment: You can use a 3rd party FTP service that has greater permission controls, you don't have to use the Marketing Cloud default FTP. As an option

Comment: It would make more sense to pass the data directly via the API into a data extension than to try and push a CSV in without using an FTP.  As @TravisNaughton stated, you are also able to use a 3rd party FTP service to import files if the SFMC FTP does not meet your needs.

Comment: Be aware, that file drop triggered automations are not supported when using 3rd party FTP

Comment: Thanks for the replies! We have some constraints, railroading us into CSVs and 'in-Marketing-Cloud' solutions. Specifically, the 3rd party can't provide an alternative (e.g., JSON) for, 6+ months. @TravisNaughton, wouldn't a 3rd party FTP still has the issue of getting the data into Marketing Cloud.

Comment: I would look at some windows command scripts to automate this transfer - it takes a bit to set up and usually requires it to be installed locally though. It  can possibly allow the user to find username and pass inside the script, but it makes it much tougher for the average person to find it.  (https://www.jscape.com/blog/using-windows-ftp-scripts-to-automate-file-transfers) or via CutieFTP (https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10407.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a way. It is VERY manual, so take it like it is, but it allows you to upload into Content Builder and then import from there as you asked for in your question.

1. Upload the file to the portfolio
2. Get the File URL from the properties page
3. Create an import/use Import Wizard
4. select 'My Computer' as import option
5. click 'browse' to open browse window
6. Paste the File URL into file name text field at bottom
7. Click Open
8. Continue as normal

This potentially could be automated via API calls, but it would require a developer to spend a good amount of hours to construct it and it would have to be completely custom.